# Search Index and Crawl

Tags: office-365-develop-tool

In my current scenario i got an app clustered SharePoint Server 2013 with both the Web servers pointed to a common DB server. Now I need to run a Search Service and crawl on another server, can I have the steps to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of steps involved in this process. You need to make a clone on the active search topoligy, start it on another server (doesn't have to be web front end) and drop the first query component. Follow these steps carefully, and you are well on your way:

> ## Step #1 - Clone the Active Search Topology
>
> ```
> # Clone the active search topology
> $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
> $active = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa -Active
> $clone = New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa -Clone –SearchTopology $active
> ```
>
> ## Step #2 - Add the New Search Component on the WFE
>
> ```
> # Add New Search Component
> $wfe = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity "<<web front end server name here>>"
> New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $wfe
> ```
>
> ## Step #3 - Start the Search Instance on the WFE# Start Instance On Different Server
>
> ```
> Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $wfe
> ```
>
> ## Step #4 - Activate the Cloned Search Topology
>
> ```
> # Activate Search Topology
> Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $clone
> ```
>
> ## Step #5 - Clone the Search Topology Again
>
> ```
> # Clone Again 
> $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
> $active = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa -Active
> $clone = New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa -Clone –SearchTopology $active
> ```
>
> ## Step #6 - Get the ComponentID to Move
>
> ```
> # Get the Search Component ID To Move
> $queryComponentID = (Get-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -SearchTopology $clone -Identity QueryProcessingComponent1).componentID
> ```
>
> ## Step #7 - Remove the Search Component from the Original Server
>
> ```
> # Remove Search Component
> Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -Identity $queryComponentID.GUID -SearchTopology $clone -confirm:$false
> ```
>
> ## Step #8 - Activate the Search Topology Again
>
> ```
> # Activate Search Topology Again
> Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $clone
> ```
>
> [image]

Reference and credits: [SharePoint 2013 Search: Moving the Query Component to a Web Front End](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.ch/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-search-moving-query.html)

Comment: I ran steps 1 and 2 on the WFE server where I currently have my index server installed and on line 2 of step2 I got the error "The search server instance on this server is not online". Then i ran steps 3 and 4 the server where I wish to run the new Index Server and on step4 I hit the error "access to this function requires a sharepoint server client license"